# Which cryptographic method does iTunes use to encrypt Backups?

Tags: itunes, backup, encryption

I am writing a little cli tool to recover data from iTunes Backups. How does iTunes encrypt its Backups?

Comment: Looks like this topic has been already answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498342/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-apple-itunes-iphone-backup

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Apple is using a standard encryption, as the FBI demonstrated for us,  its so far, uncrackable, it contains your used passwords, and other sensitive information, how are you planning on decrypting this data?

Comment: Yes ok but it's not about 'cracking'  the Backup, itself, it's about to decrypt the data which means different things. The tool requests the encryption password and then it it decrypts all data and copies them to a new folder. Basically creating a unencrypted backup from a decrypted one.

Comment: I doubt such info is available, info regarding Apples encryption, is probably and rightly so, hidden away from any one. You will require the encryption key to be able to decrypt it, now getting that, is less likely then living on mars...